# Centralized algorithm for mutual exclusion - queue usage

Tags: algorithm, distributed-computing, mutual-exclusion

Quoting from [DISTRIBUTED SYSTEMS - Principles & Paradigms](https://books.google.co.il/books/about/Distributed_Systems.html?id=UKDjLQAACAAJ&hl=en) section 6.3.2

> The coordinator takes the first item off the queue of deferred
>   requests and sends that process a grant message

So essentially, the coordinator process (or thread if we work on the same tier) is using a ***queue*** in order to buffer the requests, but the queue itself is a ***shared resource*** which needs mutual exclusion protection, so it seems like as the chicken & the egg syndrome...

My questions is how to implement the centralized algorithm, say on the very same machine, using only memory RD/RW primitives (i.e. no CAS, no mutexes etc.) C like code would be great.

The incentive for this question is simply widening my distributed system horizons.

Comment: The coordinator, eg. a network socket server with one thread per client, runs as one program one one machine. You can use a normal mutex there, as provided by the threading part of your programming language. Distributed mutual exclusion is difficult, but locally there's no problem.

Comment: @deviantfan as said in the question, my setup is one machine, using threads and the machine regular memory as the communication medium (no sockets). Moreover, one only allowed to use simple memory rd/rw, so no mutexes etc. Example : say I've 100 threads need to access a counter, how ,using of course coordinator thread and queue, achieving this end

Comment: Well, then it's communication over shared mem instead of sockets. But ... Generally, with only normal memory reading/writing on C level (no mutex, no asm...), synchronisation of threads just isn't possible. [And no, Petersons algo etc. won't work either]

Comment: @deviantfan To amplify what deviantfan said, modern multiprocessors are not sequentially consistent, so you cannot reason about their behavior in a way that would help with understanding the textbook material.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat for the sake of argument, lets assume sequential consistency (imagine hidden fences are being placed, again just as a thought process) - is it possible to have, say, 100 threads incrementing shared counter via proxy/coordinator thread, using only mem rd/rw